# Scratch files in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

I recently started C# using **Visual Studio 2022** after spending some time with Idea and Java.
I am missing the feature of scratch files as it existed in Intellij Idea.

It basically allowed us to run code snippets in our IDE, which were independent of our currently open project, and these snippets were available in all other projects.

A friend suggested *dotnetfiddle.net* but that means I have to leave the IDE and also code is not available in the future for me to refer to.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

## Visual Studio:

See https://github.com/WayneKoorts/Scratchy

## VSC (Visual Studio Code)

Look at **Scratchpads** plugin here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=buenon.scratchpads

1. Run Command Palette <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Create new file command: `Scratchpads: New scratchpad`
3. Choose file type and enjoy scratch file
4. To open closed scratch files: run command `Scratchpads: Open scratchpad`

Some features form README:

```
Scratchpads README
  Create multiple scratchpad files for doodling while you're coding.

Highlights
  Create multiple scratchpads
  Create scratchpads of different languages and file types
  Enjoy VSCode intellisense in your scratchpads
  Scratchpad are not interfering your project and can be removed at any time
```

Comment: That's Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio.

Comment: @WayneKoorts thanks for feedback and pointing out difference. Since some people found my answer valuable I added additional info in answer.

Comment: Thanks @pbaranski.  I found your answer because I was looking for such an extension and ultimately couldn't find one.  So I made one, and made it open source.  If anyone finds this via search, you can get my extension on the VS marketplace for free.  It's called Scratchy.  Source available at https://github.com/WayneKoorts/Scratchy